# Field access exception

Tags: uwp, json.net

I have an UWP app deployed to the store. When I try to deserialize the object newtonsoft throws an error.

Json string is very simple:

```
{"id":1,"IsOnline":true}
```

This only occurs on the Store release version. I've run it in Visual Studio with .Net Native and Optimize Code turned on and it works fine. I've even sideloaded the same application (release version) build from the appxbundle created when I make the package for the store.

Exception:

> System.FieldAccessException: Attempt by method
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer..ctor()' to access field
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSetting.DefaultContext' failed.

Comment: `DefaultContext` is a static [`StreamingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext?view=netcore-2.0), see https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializerSettings.cs#L442.  This type is available in .Net core, but is it available in UWP?  What happens if you try to construct one yourself in your app?

Comment: @dbc  I just make a call:
 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebServiceStatus>(JsonString); 
and receive exception.

I do not construct StreamingContext by myself. 
The problem is that I have to first publish app to the Store to reproduce issue.

Comment: Right, so what I am suggesting is, before that, try allocating a `StreamingContext` struct yourself.  See whether any exception is thrown, and if so, what it is.  I don't know what the problem is, so I'm trying to suggest ways to reproduce it outside Json.NET.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @DmitryShiryaev, I've tried allocating a `StreamingContext` and an exception is not thrown. @DmitryShiryaev, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @PMARSH Still no. I had to use DataContractSerializer instead of Json.Net just to make the app work.

Comment: It looks like your app needs some additional permission to work properly. There are some options in the UWP Project's properties. IMHO it is the only explanation.